# Strange behavior of DateList when converting string

Tags: string-manipulation, bugs, date-and-time, version-8

DateList experiences some strange behavior which i cannot explain.
This code works fine:

```
DateList[{"2012September1211:45:26", {"Year", "MonthName", "Day", 
   "Hour", ":", "Minute", ":", "Second"}}]
```

Returning

```
{2012, 9, 12, 11, 45, 26.}
```

But this code doesn't work:

```
DateList[{"2012October1211:45:26", {"Year", "MonthName", "Day", 
   "Hour", ":", "Minute", ":", "Second"}}]
```

Returning this error message:

> DateString::str: String 2012October1211:45:26 cannot be interpreted as
>   a date in format {Year,MonthName,Day,Hour,:,Minute,:,Second}. >>

The only thing i changed is the month from september to october.

Really frustrating, i'm already staring at it for 2 hours...

**Question: What am i doing wrong?**

Comment: The October version works on my end. What version of *Mathematica* are you on?

Comment: Both lines also work on version 7.

Comment: Works here too.

Comment: I had lots of problems with date parsing functions that others couldn't reproduce.  It turns out how these work depends on the regional settings of your system!  **You'll only get the documented behaviour on Windows with a US English locale.**

Comment: (With non English locals it doesn't simply use the month names I another language.  Often parsing is just broken :( )

Comment: To confirm what Szabolcs said I ran this in bash:
`expr='DateList[{"2012October1211:45:26", {"Year", "MonthName", "Day","Hour", ":", "Minute", ":", "Second"}}]'; math <<< $expr; export LANG='zu_ZA'; math <<< $expr;`

Comment: I retagged it as bugs and version-8

Comment: I'm running mma version 8.0.4.0 at Ubuntu 64-bit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solution credit to Szabolcs comment!

If you are on linux you can fix this by starting mathematica from your terminal as:

> export LANG=en_US.UTF-8; mathematica

Or if it is not in your path:

> export LANG=en_US.UTF-8; /Directory/To/Mathematica/Version/Executables/Mathematica

Comment: It works! I'm glad it wasn't some simple typo i made...

Comment: Is it in some way not wise to start mma alway with this command?